# Different kind of outputs while doing simple one word searched

Tags: discussion, search

When I just type `java` in the SO search box, I get the page with all question tagged java with link to it's tag wiki, top users on the top i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java, and the search box has the search-word parsed as `[java]`. But when I search for `sybase`, I don't see a similar page for sybase, but I see a result that did a search to find the string sybase in various posts i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sybase.

Same thing as `java` occurs for `facebook`, `bash`. And same scenario as described for `sybase` occurs for `sed`, `vi`.

So, is it something that popular tags as per SO get's recognized and leads to directly the tag page, and others go as the simple search page ?

Please clarify on this.

Comment: I think this only works for tags with lots of questions.

Comment: related : [Why are search queries inconsistently converted into tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146311/why-are-search-queries-inconsistently-converted-into-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search for a sequence of letters which is also a tag, you are redirected to the tag page if the tag is popular.

To find out the definition of popular, I binary searched the tag list (assuming the threshold must be within the first 5 pages). And it looks like the top 120 tags are considered popular.

So at the moment [c#-4.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) is the last.