# When does search use keywords and when does it auto-convert them to tags?

Tags: support, search

When I use the search engine, when and why does it auto-convert some keywords to tags?

For example, when I input "jav" in the search engine, it gives me 283 results including relevant questions and answers.

When I input "java" in the search engine, it links to the tagged questions page. How does that work?

Answer (score 12):

The "formal" way to search by tag is wrapping the tag name with square brackets, e.g. `[java]`, which then redirects the user to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java instead of performing actual search.

However, this isn't very intuitive, and probably many users typed just "java" (without quotes) in the search box expecting all tagged questions and getting instead bunch of search results.

To remedy this, the team implemented at some point mechanism that:

1. If the search term is not wrapped with quotes and
2. contains no spaces and
3. there exists a tag with this exact name and it's among the top X tags (sorted by popularity i.e. amount of questions having the tag, X [used to be 60](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146312/152859) but quick test disproved it)

Then it's treating as if the user typed `[search-word-here]` and redirecting to that tag page.

Any other search term is treated as ordinary search term and results are served as you noticed.

To search for posts containing just a term that is also a tag name, just wrap with quotes, e.g. [searching for posts containing "java"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22java%22).

Bonus tip: you can even search for posts containing "java" inside questions that are not tagged java, with such search term: [`"java" -[java]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22java%22+-%5Bjava%5D).

Comment: I think it is not friendly for users. Why doesn't SO give me some results include the relevant posts and tags when i typed "java" (without quotes) in the search box? Maybe I want to find some posts or tags that are relevant with java.

Comment: @xshsinap feel free to start new feature request, personally I won't support it since the current behavior is good.

Comment: The auto-conversion to a tag only applies to the top X tags, I believe, and I cannot recall what X is here. Something like 40 or 100.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, will check it further and update the answer.

Comment: @xshsinap "Maybe I want to find some posts or tags that are relevant with java" arguably, all posts relevant to java will be tagged with the [java] tag, so this current behaviour should suit your needs. Otherwise, you'd get all sorts of unrelated things  "This PHP code should suit you, but it can be done in Java too, Google it" (etc). Search functionality is a difficult thing to get right, especially on such a site as Stack where there's a lot of content to consider.

Comment: @ShadowWizard   I confirmed that X is 60.

Comment: @James  Maybe I want to have the power of choice. But now SO gives me the links to tagged questions. I feel a bit inconvenient.

Comment: @xshsinap nope, not 60 on Stack Overflow. "function" without quotes turns into a tag and it's way below the top 60 tags.

Comment: @xshsinap I understand you want choice, of course that is great if easily possible, but as said, search functionality can be wild beasts and especially on sites such as Stack with a huge amount of searchable items. It might be changeable, perhaps you should search for questions here on MSE for the same thing, and if nothing found submit a feature-request to see if it can be *tweaked*

Answer (score 1):

Searching in general is covered in the [Help Centre topic: "How do I search?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching). Basic search ideas include:

- using square brackets for specific tags: `[java] port` searches for mentions of "port" within the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag.
- using quotes to find a specific phrase, or to search a string of special characters, like `"java coffee"`, or `"<%# java"`;
- limiting your search to just the title of a question by using `title:` followed by the search term. Likewise, search the body only (exclude the title) with `body:"phrase here"`;
- limiting search to *just your* posts by adding `user:me java` searches all of your posts for the word "java";
- exclusion of a tag, term or phrase, via the `-` prefix: `java -coffee` finds posts that mention what certain programmers enjoy without a reference to the caffeinated beverage, while `[java] -[c#]` includes only posts tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) *and not* [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).
- inclusion of multiple tags via a traditional `or`; like `[java] or [coffee]` will include posts tagged with either [java](/questions/tagged/java) *or* [coffee](/questions/tagged/coffee) *or both*. In contrast, `[java] [coffee]` searches for posts tagged with [java](/questions/tagged/java) *and* [coffee](/questions/tagged/coffee).
- using wildcards to broaden results via an asterisk (`*`) anywhere in the word, like `encour*` or `Ex*nge`.

There are also some advanced search techniques to focus your search based on

- Ranges (score, views, answers)
- Dates (created, last active)
- Users (users, favorites, tags)
- Boolean (accepted, code, answered, closed, duplicate, migrated, locked, notice, wiki)
- Other (URLs, question/answer)