# Searching for a word within posts randomly returns tag results instead

Tags: bug, search

When I use the search function within [LawSE](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour) to find posts with a particular word, it randomly adds square brackets [ ] around what I'm looking for and so only shows tag results.

I've carried a brief dip-sample and all these return tag results:

> Germany, Canada, Australia, police, lawyer, trademark, privacy, GDPR, software
>
> (*there are more but hopefully these are enough.*)

[image]

However, the following search terms return results with them within the body of a post regardless of the tags (as it should be, surely?):

> France, Scotland, Austria, API, HOA, appeal
>
> (*NB some of these are also tags in their own right*)

[image]

It matters not whether I search from the Home page or the Questions page. I am not following any tags and I have cleared my cache and cookies many times over.

Comment: another dupe target: [Why are search queries inconsistently converted into tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146311/why-are-search-queries-inconsistently-converted-into-tags)

Comment: As noted by @Luuklag in the duplicate *You can circumvent this conversion by putting your search term in quotes. Example: "support" or "stackoverflow".* Thanks!

Comment: I edited also the post that this is closed as duplicate of to include that bit there.